# How to get Flowable<List<Foo>> from 'Bar' Object with One-to-many relations 'Foo' using realm and Rxjava

Tags: java, android, kotlin, realm, rx-android

Let say I have model class like this. [I copy from here.](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/kotlinExample/src/main/kotlin/io/realm/examples/kotlin/model/Person.kt)

```
open class Person(
        @PrimaryKey var id: Long = 0,
        var name: String = "",
        var age: Int = 0,
        var dog: Dog? = null,
        var cats: RealmList<Cat> = RealmList(),

) : RealmObject() {

}
```

There are many people and each person has one or more cats.

My question is how to I get `Flowable<List<Cat>>` or similar (every cats that people own). From this flowable list, I want to list every cats (sorted by name) and display with RecyclerView.Adapter. Please help me how to achieve the cat list. Thank you.

So far I can only get `Flowable<Cat>` by using like the following.

```
mRealm.where(Person::class.java)
                .findAllAsync().asFlowable()
                .filter { p -> p.isLoaded }
                .flatMap { p -> Flowable.fromIterable(p).flatMap { b -> Flowable.fromIterable(b.cats) }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
open class Cat : RealmObject() {
    var name: String? = null

    @LinkingObjects("cats")
    val owners : RealmResults<Person>? = null;
}

RealmResults<Cat> ownedCats = realm.where(Cat::class.java)
                                   .isNotEmpty("owners")
                                   .findAllAsync()...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not sure I want to use LinkingObject for now.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it which I think the answer for me. I think I have to use map first, then flatMap to flatten as a list and collect and sort these back. Here is a simple program with debug output to show how I get the `Flowable<List<Cat>>`.

```
    mRealm.executeTransaction {
        val person = mRealm.createObject(Person::class.java, 1)
        person.name = "John"

        val firstCat = mRealm.createObject(Cat::class.java)
        firstCat.name = "Kitty"
        person.cats.add(firstCat)

        val secondCat = mRealm.createObject(Cat::class.java)
        secondCat.name = "Ashes"
        person.cats.add(secondCat)
    }

    mRealm.executeTransaction {
        val person = mRealm.createObject(Person::class.java, 2)
        person.name = "Bob"

        val firstCat = mRealm.createObject(Cat::class.java)
        firstCat.name = "Daisy"
        person.cats.add(firstCat)

        val secondCat = mRealm.createObject(Cat::class.java)
        secondCat.name = "Missy"
        person.cats.add(secondCat)
    }

    val flowableListOfCat: Flowable<List<Cat>> = mRealm.where(Person::class.java)
            .findAllAsync().asFlowable()
            .filter { person -> person.isLoaded }
            .map { p -> p.flatMap { a -> a.cats }.sortedBy { c -> c.name } }

    flowableListOfCat
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe { catList -> catList.forEach { cat -> Log.d("Cat", "" + cat.name) } }
```

At debug output,

`D/Cat: Ashes
D/Cat: Daisy
D/Cat: Kitty
D/Cat: Missy`